# LINQ TO XML retrieving Child Element Value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML

```
<ABC xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
    <ReceiptId>
        <IdValue>123</IdValue>
    </ReceiptId>
    <ClientOrderId>
        <IdValue>345</IdValue>
    </ClientOrderId>
    <AccessPoint>
        <Description>My Description</Description>
    </AccessPoint>
    <ABCStatus>
        <Status>Error</Status>
        <Details>ERRORS:
 Talent is already in an active process for this opening.
        </Details>
        <StatusDate>2015-08-05</StatusDate>
    </ABCStatus>
</ABC>
```

I am trying to retrieve the element value 345 nested in IdValue and ClientOrderId

I have used the Linq to xml code in C# to retrieve the value with no luck

```
XDocument XMLResults = XDocument.Parse(sResult);

var sClientOrderID =
        from nodeAElem in XMLResults.Root.Elements("ABC")
        from nodeA1Elem in nodeAElem.Elements("ClientOrderId")
        from nodeA11Elem in nodeA1Elem.Elements("IdValue")
        select nodeA11Elem.Value;
```

also need to retrieve the Status Elements value which is Error for the above xml.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your XML document is using a namespace, you have to use it in your query to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your XML document is using a namespace, you have to use it in your query to make it work.
2. `Root` already brings you to `ABC` element, so you don't have to call `Elements("ABC")`
3. You're looking for single value, so you probably want to use `Element` instead of `Elements`.

```
var ns = (XNamespace)"http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15";
var sClientOrderID = (int)XMLResults.Root
                                    .Element(ns + "ClientOrderId")
                                    .Element(ns + "IdValue");
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin you cleared up all my mistakes perfectly ... really appreciate your feedback